# Getting angle back from a sin/cos conversion

Tags: math, angle, trigonometry

I want to reverse a `sin`/`cos` operation to get back an angle, but I can't figure out what I should be doing.

I have used `sin` and `cos` on an angle in radians to get the x/y vector as such:

```
double angle = 90.0 * M_PI / 180.0;  // 90 deg. to rad.
double s_x = cos( angle );
double s_y = sin( angle );
```

Given `s_x` and `s_y`, is it possible to get back the angle? I thought `atan2` was the function to use, but I'm not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`atan2(s_y, s_x)` should give you the correct angle. Maybe you have reversed the order of `s_x` and `s_y`. Also, you can use the `acos` and `asin` functions directly on `s_x` and `s_y` respectively.

Comment: my x/y were indeed reversed as I had some code that was assigning the sin to x and some other bits were assigning sin to y.

Answer (score 12):

I use the **acos** function to get back the angle from the given s_x cosinus. But because several angles may result to the same cosinus (for example cos(+60°) = cos(-60°) = 0.5), it's not possible to get back the angle directly from s_x. So I also use the **sign of s_y** to get back the sign of the angle.

```
// Java code
double angleRadian = (s_y > 0) ? Math.acos(s_x) : -Math.acos(s_x);
double angleDegrees = angleRadian * 180 / Math.PI;
```

for the specific case of (s_y == 0), it does not matter to take +acos or -acos because it means the angle is 0° (+0° or -0° are the same angles) or 180° (+180° or -180° are the same angles).

Answer (score 3):

In math is reverse operation for sin and cos. This is arcsin and arccos.
I don't know what programming language you use. But usually if it have cos and sin function then it can have reverse function.

Answer (score 2):

asin(s_x), acos(s_y), perhaps, if you are using c.

Answer (score 1):

```
double angle_from_sin_cos( double sinx, double cosx ) //result in -pi to +pi range
{
    double ang_from_cos = acos(cosx);
    double ang_from_sin = asin(sinx);
    double sin2 = sinx*sinx;
    if(sinx<0)
    {
        ang_from_cos = -ang_from_cos;
        if(cosx<0) //both negative
            ang_from_sin = -PI -ang_from_sin;
    }
    else if(cosx<0)
        ang_from_sin = PI - ang_from_sin;
    //now favor the computation coming from the
    //smaller of sinx and cosx, as the smaller
    //the input value, the smaller the error
    return (1.0-sin2)*ang_from_sin + sin2*ang_from_cos;
}
```