# How do you get the angle from sin?

Tags: math

I have a value for sin:

```
var opposite = 100;
var hypotenuse = 228;

var sin = opposite/hypotenuse;
```

I want to know what angle that is. On my calculator I can just do sin^-1(). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079127/getting-angle-back-from-a-sin-cos-conversion) thread says to use asin but when I use asin I get [45°](http://jsfiddle.net/45LR3/). The correct angle is 25°.

Comment: `asin` returns result in radians

Comment: asin = arcsine = sin^-1. Different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Because the arcus sinus returns result in radians and radian is defined as

[image]

you should convert result to degrees this way

```
var opposite = 100;
var hypotenuse = 228;

var sin = opposite/hypotenuse;

var angle = Math.asin(sin)*180/Math.PI;

document.body.innerHTML = angle;
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/o69xjayh/