# How to reverse sin/cos encoding of time series?

Tags: time-series

https://towardsdatascience.com/cyclical-features-encoding-its-about-time-ce23581845ca encodes a timestamp in terms of `sin(x)`, `cos(x)`. First, they map `X`'s "hour of day" and "day of year" to the range `[0, 2*PI]`. Finally, they feed the value into `sin()` and `cos()`.

Given `sin(x) = y` and `cos(x) = z`, how do I get back the original "hour of day" and "day of year"?

Comment: Each `{y,z}` pair is mapped from an indeterminate and potentially infinite number of `x` values. So it is not generally possible to recover the original `x`. At best you can get back a *principal value*.

Comment: @njuffa I've clarified the question. `x` does not have an infinite range. It must lie within `[0, 2*PI]`. If we can reverse `sin/cos` back to the input `[0, 2*PI]` I can then map back to the time of day, and day of year associated with `x`.

Comment: In that case, use `atan2`.

Comment: @njuffa That did it. Thank you! If you post a more elaborate answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: This question seems to be duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079127/getting-angle-back-from-a-sin-cos-conversion)

Comment: @njuffa Agreed. I'll flag it as a duplicate. Thanks again.